# Deepl API: Translate single word with context from whole sentence

Tags: deepl

I want to translate single words out of a whole sentence using the DeepL API.

For example, the sentence might be: "How may I help you?"

If I now want to translate the word "help", DeepL might treat it as a noun (the help) or as verb (to help), both resulting in different outcomes in, for example, German language.

Is there a possibility to send the whole sentence as context to help DeepL disambiguate the word?

I tried to mark the word that I want to isolate. For example:

"How may I "help" you?"

But this seems to destroy the result or be ignored by DeepL.

Comment: Not sure if that exists. You could perhaps translate the full phrase first, resulting in `Wie kann ich Ihnen helfen?`, and then `help` on its own, which gets me `Hilfe`, and alternatives `helfen`, `Unterstützung` (using the web UI, but surely the API will provide similar data?) - and then look for which version you find in the translation of the full phrase ...? (But with the complexity of German declination and cases, that will probably not work all too well for more complex cases, I suppose.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. As far as I understand, the API only returns one translation at the moment :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the answer. The docs describe [here](https://www.deepl.com/de/docs-api/translate-text/translate-text#:%7E:text=/languages%20endpoint.-,context,-optional) how to use context.

Attention: As stated by the docs, this feature is still in alpha as of now:

"The context parameter is an alpha feature as defined in section 3.1.5 of our terms and conditions. This means it could be changed or deprecated by DeepL at any point and without advance notice."